# How to display all categories in magento project

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

am new to magento 1.7 and am using celebrity theme now what i want is to add all the categories to be displayed in left side bar , i have browsed through n tried many but none of them are working (May be due to Celebrity theme). So can any one help me on this ASAP. PLEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add like this

go to your layout.xml and add like this

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml
```

Open this Xml file and paste this code.

```
<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
</reference>
```

open this file ..

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml
```

paste this code:

```
 <?php
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');


foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getName() == $current_cat) {
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a>\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($subcat).'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT**

**LIST ALL CATEGORIES**

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>

<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php //if ($currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                        <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                    </a>

                                    <?php $_category1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                     <?php $_subcategories1 = $_category1->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                     <?php if (count($_subcategories1) > 0): ?>
                         <ul>
                             <?php foreach($_subcategories1 as $_subcategory1): ?>
                                 <li>
                                     <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory1) ?>">
                                         <?php echo $_subcategory1->getName() ?>
                                     </a>
                                 </li>
                             <?php endforeach; ?>
                         </ul>
                     <?php endif; ?>


                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php // endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: there is no catalog.xml file in the root you mentioned

Comment: then use the file : `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/layout/catalog.xml`. If the file does not exist, copy it from `base/default` theme. Also instead of making an other instance of the block (`$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();`) you can use `$obj = $this`.

Comment: Hai liyakat , thanks it worked but its is displaying only the navigation menu categories , i want all categories(NOT only top menu catagories) , Please help ASAP

Comment: you can take reference from here

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/

Comment: No in this link also only top catagories i need all categories

Comment: getStoreCategories()  returns only top menu categories , same issue only menu categories and sub categories of menu categories are displaying

Comment: Check this link http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/all-category-listing-in-magento/ but when i try with all categories to display its displaying default category also please help me . As am new to Magento

Comment: as i updated my answer it is working me for any block in magento